# Amplify react native custom SignIn

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I am using `withAuthenticator` component of AWS `aws-amplify-react-native` from AWS amplify. I am able to do this for signUp `<SignUp signUpConfig={signUpConfig} />`, I want to customise signIn, ConfirmSignUp, ForgotPassword screen also without writing my own component from scratch.

signUp config seems to be doable because `signUpConfig` is part of this class https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify-react-native/src/Auth/SignUp.tsx#L47

But same is not available for singIn and other components. Is there an alternate to have customise signIn, ConfirmSignUp, ForgotPassword screens.

Note[1] - I am not able to use `Authenticator` component of `aws-amplify-react-native`, SignUp screen is shown on half of the page, apparently it have rendering bugs.

Note[2] - I am not able to use `Authenticator` from `@aws-amplify/ui-react` also, Seems its built only for react and not for react-native. Although doc says its for react-native also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Auth` from aws-amplify. I did something like this.

```
/* Import the Amplify Auth API */
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

export default function LoginScreen() {

   const login = async () => {
      if (validateInputFields(formData)) {
         try {
           await Auth.signIn(formData.email, formData.password);
           goToHomeScreen();
         } catch (err) { console.log({ err }); }
      }
   }

   return (
      <View>
         
         {/* Email and Password fields /*}

         <Button title="Login" onPress={() => login()} />
      </View>
   )
}
```

The doc has the API for SignUp as well

https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/custom-auth-flow/q/platform/js/